# cassandra Datastax exception NoClassDefFoundError using nodetool

Tags: cassandra

As per [this article](http://www.datastax.com/resources/articles/setup-and-monitor-a-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-windows), I could generate tokens, configured `Cassandra.yaml` on both machines and restarted services on both machines.

After that need to check for the new cluster using node tool utility by entering the following command: `nodetool –h localhost ring`

The output shows following exception:

```
C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apace cassandra\bin>nodetool -h localhost ring     
Starting NodeTool
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files\DataStax    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\DataStax ...
```

Can anyone help me resolving this issues? Seems like it could not find the jar files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the classpath quoting bug that was fixed (for the not-yet-released 1.0.8 version) in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3744.  You can download a fixed nodetool.bat from https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.0/bin/nodetool.bat in the meantime.

I can't think of anything you'd want nodetool for that opscenter doesn't do better, though.